# What's the replacement for webpack-dev-server in Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've noticed that installing `webpack-dev-server@webpack/webpack#next` actually installs webpack (without any warning). However, there's no `webpack-dev-server` executable any more.

Is there a replacement for this in Webpack 4, or do I need a separate web server?

It was really convenient to quickly spin up a web server with hot reloading. What's the recommended way to do that in Webpack 4?

(Why I'm bothering with Webpack 4 at all? Because it supports native .mjs modules)

Comment: Isn't GH issue a better place for webpack 4 questions since it's still in beta state?

Comment: @Xlee: perhaps, but asking these sorts of questions, as opposed to filing bug reports, usually get me sent elsewhere from [many](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18001#issuecomment-355525409) OSS [projects'](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/7850#issuecomment-273263540) repos.

Comment: After spending the last 12 hours attempting to upgrade from Webpack 3 -> 4 (with the help of 50+ blog posts and GH issues), I would suggest anyone else who is considering for new ways to torture themselves to be happy that their tool-chain is working and turn back. Dependency hell doesn't begin to describe what awaits.

Answer (score 6):

Today were released [webpack v4.0.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.0.0) and [webpack-dev-server v3.0.0](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v3.0.0)

Just as Shaknar said, you just need to install the latest versions (including `webpack-cli`):

```
yarn add webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server --dev
```

You can also check this [webpack-demo project](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) I made for a meetup last week.

Comment: hot module replacement

Answer (score 3):

you need to install `webpack-dev-server@next` , `webpack-cli` and `webpack@next` to run webpack 4 for now  when it will be released you dont need `@next` to install latest version

Comment: Turns out `yarn add webpack-dev-server@next webpack@next` is sufficient, but Webpack's GitHub repo says [webpack-dev-server is in maintenance mode](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server#project-in-maintenance). Will it actually be released for Webpack 4, or is it being abandoned?

Comment: Fwiw, it looks like people are talking about this, but I couldn't find anything specifically promised. https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1295 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/1243

Comment: What a mess. I'm going back to webpack 3 and not upgrading for the rest of my life.